# How to use mobile touch events with pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

What is the syntax for mobile touch events in javascript? I tried:

`window.document.body.ontouchstart = function() { alert(); }`

and

`window.document.body.touchstart = function() { alert(); }`

It doesn't give any error. And nothing happens on touching the webpage. It seems like `addEventListener` is the way to go. But why doesn't `window.document.body.ontouchstart` directly work?

Answer (score 3):

```
var theElement = document.getElementById("theElement");

theElement.addEventListener("touchstart", handlerFunction, false);

function handlerFunction(event) {
alert();
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't `window.document.body.ontouchstart` work?

Comment: @user31782 you need `addEventListener()` method, so target the body element and then attach the event. `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].addEventListener('touchstart'....`

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
function foo(event) {
  alert();
}

var el = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
  el.addEventListener("touchstart", foo(), false);

//or 

window.document.body.addEventListener("touchstart", foo(), false);
```

- [Event listner documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp)
- [example jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/tiagofabre/ey794hjs/)